# Run ansible task if the client is not in ad domain

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Currently I am creating a playbook to automate our initial server setup for ubuntu server 20.04.4 LTS. I've created the following simple task:

```yaml
  - name: Join Domain domain.group
    expect:
      command: realm join -U domainuser domain.group
      responses:
        Password for *: "{{domain_join_pw}}"
```

This works just fine, but once the task is done and I run the play again it gets interrupted with the following message:

```
["realm: Already joined to this domain"]
```

Is there a way to check if the client is already in the domain and only run the task when it's not?

I tried the ansible_fqdn and ansible_domain fact like this:

```yaml
  - name: Join Domain domain.group
    expect:
      command: realm join -U domainuser domain.group
      responses:
        Password for *: "{{domain_join_pw}}"
    when: ansible_fqdn != "domain.group"
```

I am quite new to Ansible, I think it's not hard to do but can't find out how.
Thanks for every awnser.

Comment: Have you considered using the [dedicated module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_domain_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-domain-module)?

Comment: @Zeitounator, as I interpret the module description and source, the `win_domain_module` is for Windows targets whereby the question is about a Linux target joining a Windows domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is assumed that the domain is registered within a variable.

```yaml
DOMAIN: "domain.group"
```

You could use the following generic and not yet tested example to enhance your use case.

```yaml
- name: Check if system is already domain joined
  shell:
    cmd: realm list | grep {{ DOMAIN }}
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: domain_joined
  failed_when: domain_joined.rc !=0 and domain_joined.rc !=1
```

and let tasks later run only when not domain joined, in example

```yaml
when: not domain_joined | bool
```

*... currently I have domain joined systems only, therefore I could not run a full test with a not joined system yet.*

You may have also a look into the command

```sh
sssctl domain-status ${DOMAIN}
Online status: Online

Active servers:
AD Global Catalog: not connected
AD Domain Controller: ad.example.com

Discovered AD Global Catalog servers:
None so far.

Discovered AD Domain Controller servers:
- ad.example.com
```

or `{{ DOMAIN }}` when used from within Ansible, check the output as well how to filter and register the result for further usage.